# How to store data from XML file to SQLite database in android

Tags: android, xml, database, sqlite, url

I am developing an application -- When a user is successfully logged in, an XML file is fetched from a URL and the XML data is displayed in list view.

How do I store that data in SQLite database, such that an offline user can see the data stored in the  database? I also want to create a refresh button, which displays an updated XML file and stores it in SQLite, when it is clicked.

Comment: [link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html

It is the best approach towards your requirement.

Comment: Can you give me what kind of information you have? Do you want to store the entire xml content as a huge string and parse it each time you need to access it from the database? Do you want to store each xml element of your xml file independently? We need to have more information about what you want to store, and how it is right now. You should also give us some code snippets showing what you have done so far. Last, but not least, begin to check the documentation about sqlite databse in android.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1)Get that Xml

2)Parse the xml using sax or any other parser you prefer 
For parsing [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/)

3)Use the parsed data as you need in your case put it into Database 
For Database [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

4)Populate the list view For listview [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)